# Update/Upgrade PHP MongoDB driver

Tags: php, mongodb, shell, terminal

Im currently running Php MongoDb version 1.2.10 and I'm wanting to update this version to the most recent/stable.

How would one go about doing this? Im assuming it would be via terminal and using pear or pecl command?

Any Help or advice is greatly appreciated :)

Update :
I did the following within terminal to install the latest version

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

Which has installed version 1.5.6. But after restarting my MAMP server the extension is still stating 1.2.10. Is there something I need to change in my php.ini file? I have already added `extension=mongo.so`

Comment: Now `mongo` is not maintained and You should install `mongodb` driver. More info: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/

Answer (score 4):

`sudo pecl upgrade mongodb` worked for me today.

Comment: I had to do `sudo pecl uninstall mongodb`  then `sudo pecl upgrade mongodb`

Answer (score 1):

If you ran `sudo pecl install mongo`, you likely upgraded the driver for the system install of PHP, which is in a different path than MAMP. There should be a `pecl` binary within the MAMP path (e.g. `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin`), which should be run instead. You may find [this blog article](http://lukepeters.me/blog/setting-up-mongodb-with-php-and-mamp) as helpful walk-through for the process.